# Compare two wsdl files to be equal

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl

I have an older webservice and I want to rewrite some code. In the end the new wsdl should be equal/same than the "old" wsdl.

The problem is, that both WSDL files have different ordering of fields ...

How can I gurantee, that users do not have any problems due to the code changes and can still use their clients, because the interface has noc changes? How can I compare both wsdl files, if both have the same meaning/interface? Does someone knows a tool to compare the two wsdl files?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8064101/xml-wsdl-comparison-tool) you can find the answer.